# Can we send email using win32com.client without opening Outlook application?

Tags: python, server, outlook, smtp, win32com

We are using the below code to send email which works fine.

However we want to utilize this script on a server that has outlook installed but not always running.

```
import win32com.client as win32
def send_email_with_attachment(attachment=None):
    outlook = win32.Dispatch("outlook.application")
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = "abc@gmail.com"
    mail.CC = ""
    mail.Subject = "New test"
    mail.Body = "From Macro"
    mail.Permission = 3 # Enable encryption
    if attachment:
        mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)
     mail.Send()
attachment_path = r"C:\Users\iinderje\check.csv" 
send_email_with_attachment(attachment_path)
```

Can somebody suggest how we can fulfill this requirement?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: have the script start the outlook app and close outlook when done